# How to stream download data from current view in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I am making a basic database application that allows users to submit search parameters through a form and have the results displayed in a view. I create a query from an Eloquent model, paginate, and then send the results to a view.

I would like to place a link on the results view that lets users download the results of their query in a csv file, but stream the data rather than create a file and then serve it. My problem is that I don't know how to pass the query from the results page through a route to another controller that handles the download.

The information I have found about sending data to a route involves sending parameters for a url which I am not sure helps me.

I was thinking I could cache the results by sending the data from the controller handling the query to the controller handling the download before sending it to a view, but I am not sure how to accomplish this or if Laravel provides a better way to do what I want.

Comment: Are you using a specific excel library, like maatwebsite/excel? They often have a method for downloading csv files from memory. Otherwise there is `response()->streamDownload()` if you're generating it yourself on the fly.

Comment: I am not using any libraries. I know about `response()->streamDownload()` but I don't know how I can do that from within a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I do it with Laravel 5.6 in `view` when user wants to download a `csv` file. Please note that you should pass `Builder` object instead of `LengthAwarePaginator`. Also note the `send()` method after `streamDownload` which I had to figure out myself.

```
/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder $results */
$callback = function () use ($results) {
    $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    // Set column names from the first result keys
    fputcsv($file, array_keys((array)$results->first()));

    // Get results in chunks to stream large downloads
    $results->chunk(1000,
        function ($rows) use ($file) {
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                fputcsv($file, (array)$row);
            }
        }
    );

    fclose($file);
};
$headers = [
    'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
];

return response()->streamDownload($callback, 'filename.csv', $headers)->send();
```